# Swift iOS adapt font size to frame

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to adapt the font size of a text element whose length varies greatly so that it fills the whole frame where it is located and no word needs to be truncated (in a iOS app). In the screenshot below, I would like the sentence to reach the buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Please find below the structure of my code. I have seen a few threads on SO dealing with this issue, but I have not been able to replicate the solution, because of my poor skills in Swift... If someone were so kind as to give me a detailed explanation of what lines of code should be inserted and where to place them, I'd be very grateful!

I have tried to adjust the font size so to say manually, by incrementing or decrementing it via a function according to the length of the string that Text receives as its argument, but it only yielded a mess, because long words need their own separate line, which mars my computation.

With thanks,

Julien

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import CoreServices
import CoreData
import MediaPlayer

struct ContentView: View {

// Various functions
    
    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
                
                var currentSentence = "string of variable length, could be a long or a very short sentence"
                Text(currentSentence) // the variable currentSentence contains a string whose length varies greatly
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .light, design: .serif))
                
                HStack {

                    Spacer()
                    // Play button
                    Button(action: {
                    // Action
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "play.square.fill").resizable()
                            .frame(width: 150.0, height: 200.0, alignment: .bottom)
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    Spacer()
                    // Pause button
                    Button(action: {
                    // Action
                    }){
                        Image(systemName: "square.slash").resizable()
                            .frame(width: 150.0, height: 200.0)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    Spacer()

               }
            }
            .frame(
                  minWidth: 0,
                  maxWidth: .infinity,
                  minHeight: 0,
                  maxHeight: .infinity,
                  alignment: .topLeading
                )
        }
    }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: You'll likely have more success here if you include a [mre]. The code you've included doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I have rectified and slightly expanded the code outline, it now compiles and runs. I hope my goal is sufficiently clear, if there's anything else that I should state or add, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .minimumScaleFactor on the text and set the text font to the maximum.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 0) {
            
            var currentSentence = "string of variable length, could be a long or a very short sentence"
            Text(currentSentence)
                .font(.system(size: 100, weight: .light, design: .serif))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1) 
            Spacer()
            HStack (alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
                
                Spacer()
                    // Play button
                Button(action: {
                        // Action
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "play.square.fill").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150.0, height: 200.0, alignment: .bottom)
                }
                Spacer()
                    // Pause button
                Button(action: {
                        // Action
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "square.slash").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150.0, height: 200.0)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
                Spacer()
                
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom])
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

In some cases there might be little bit space between text and buttons, It means new line with bigger font can't fit there.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works wonderfully, I would never have come upon this solution by myself. I will have thankful thoughts for you whenever I use my app!